# MVVM with dynamic child's possible?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a simple form that as a dynamic set of Parent Labels ( could be 1 -10 labels ) that is updated on a timer, if all is good these labels stay green like:

[image]

If however one of the parents has a status change, i am trying to then display the offending child or childs and result in somewthing like this:

[image]

then once status returns to normal revert back to the original layout ( as above )

so currently i have a view like this :

```
<Grid> 
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource = "{Binding Path = CIs}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Label Content = "{Binding Path = NodeName, Mode = OneWay}" 
                        Background = "{Binding Path = NodeStatus, Mode = OneWay}"
                        Tag="{Binding Path = Nodeid, Mode = OneWay}"
                        Foreground="White"
                        FontFamily="Arial Black"
                        HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"                            
                        BorderBrush="Black" 
                        BorderThickness="1,1,1,1"/>                        
                </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl> 
</Grid>
```

a viewmodel populating the view with a simple add:

```
if (Node.level == 3)
{
    CIs.Add(new CI { NodeName = Node.name, NodeStatus = Node.status, Nodeid = Node.id });
}
```

and the basic model :

```
public class CIModel {}

public class CI : INotifyPropertyChanged {
  private string nodeName;
  private string nodeStatus;
  private string nodeid;

    public string NodeName { 
     get { 
        return nodeName; 
     }

     set { 
        if (nodeName != value) { 
           nodeName = value; 
           RaisePropertyChanged("NodeName"); 
        } 
     } 
  }

 public string Nodeid
    {
        get
        {
            return nodeid;
        }

        set
        {
            if (nodeid != value)
            {
                nodeid = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("Nodeid");
            }
        }
    }

    public string NodeStatus
    {
        get
        {
            return nodeStatus;
        }

        set
        {
            if (nodeStatus != value)
            {
                nodeStatus = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("NodeStatus");
            }
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

  private void RaisePropertyChanged(string property) {
     if (PropertyChanged != null) {
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
     } 
  }
```

would creating a child view somehow on the parent status change be a possible way? or can i create all the parent and childs and toggle there visibility when there status changes?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you mean something like this?

[image]

```cs
// Put this in MainWindow()
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    new Demo(this);
}
```

```cs
// Demo code
public class Demo
{
    public Demo(FrameworkElement view)
    {
        View = view;
        View.DataContext = this;
        StartDemo();
    }

    private FrameworkElement View { get; }

    public ObservableCollection<Parent> Parents { get; } = new ObservableCollection<Parent>();

    public async void StartDemo()
    {
        var delay = 500;
        foreach (var index in Enumerable.Range(0, 5))
        {
            var item = new Parent { Name = $"Parent {index + 1}" };
            Parents.Add(item);
            await Task.Delay(delay);
        }

        // Add errors
        for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            Parents[1].Errors.Add(new Child { Name = $"Child {i + 1}" });
            await Task.Delay(delay);
        }

        // Remove errors
        while (Parents[1].Errors.Any())
        {
            Parents[1].Errors.RemoveAt(Parents[1].Errors.Count - 1);
            await Task.Delay(delay);
        }

        // Remove parents
        while (Parents.Any())
        {
            Parents.RemoveAt(Parents.Count-1);
            await Task.Delay(delay);
        }
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Child (error item)
/// </summary>
public class Child
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

/// <summary>
/// Parent
/// </summary>
public class Parent : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public Parent()
    {
        System.Collections.Specialized.CollectionChangedEventManager.AddHandler(Errors,
            delegate
            {
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Status));
            });
    }

    private string _name;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set { _name = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
    }

    public string Status { get { return Errors.Any() ? "ERROR" : "OK"; } }

    /// <summary>
    /// Children/errors
    /// </summary>
    public ObservableCollection<Child> Errors { get; } = new ObservableCollection<Child>();

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

```xml
<!-- Xaml -->
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Parents}"
              Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Parent}">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="ParentColumn" />
                    <ColumnDefinition  />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <!-- Parent label -->
                <Label Content="{Binding Path=Name}"
                       x:Name="Label"/>

                <!-- Errors -->
                <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Errors}"
                              Grid.Column="1">
                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Child}">
                            <Label Content="{Binding Path=Name}"
                                   Background="Red" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                </ItemsControl>
            </Grid>
            <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                <!-- Parent is ok -->
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Status}"
                             Value="OK">
                    <Setter TargetName="Label" Property="Background" Value="Green" />
                </DataTrigger>


                <!-- Parent is not ok -->
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Status}"
                             Value="ERROR">
                    <Setter TargetName="Label" Property="Background" Value="Red" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </DataTemplate.Triggers>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: is it possible to hide the first empty child? i have set the sizetocontent option and when the initial parents are added there is a blank white column of the same size to the right, ideally when the parents are OK the form width should only be the width of the paretn label, then expand per child?

Comment: `SizeToContent` should work. You could simply be hitting the minimum window size. Either increase the width of the parent, or use `WindowStyle="None"`